# Shapefiles in geodatabase not visible in ArcGIS Pro but can open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase

I can open a shapefile from a geodatabase in QGIS but it isn't visible in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0. Has anyone else had this problem.

Comment: Please provide more information on your database, possible symbologies/settings/properties, and your workflow.

Comment: Hi Erik, I created a filegeodatabase in ArcGIS Pro and used FME workbench to transfer the shapefiles into the geodatabase.

Comment: Shapefiles shouldnt be in a file geodatabase. Do you mean that you converted them to feature classes in a file geodatabase?

Comment: But I can use them in QGIS? Is this specific to ArcGIS Pro? I'm following instructions in a university assignment that require me to create a file geodatabase to host the shapefiles.

Comment: You have saved the .shp (etc) files in the .gdb folder. You haven't actually converted your shapefile to a file geodatabase featureclass. Move your .shp (etc) files out of the .gdb directory and ArcGIS Pro will be able to read them.

Answer (score 2):

I saved the shapefiles to a folder instead and they are now visible.